# Word macro working on every document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a macro in Word and it works every time I open ANY of Word documents. I don't know what is the reason for such an action and I'd like to ask you why?

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Dim fso As Object
Dim f As Object
Dim plik As Object
Dim sciezka As String

ActiveDocument.Content.Select
Selection.Delete

ActiveDocument.Select

sciezka = Application.ActiveDocument.Path & "\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(Application.ActiveDocument.Path)

For Each plik In f.Files
    If Not Left(Right(plik.Name, 8), 4) = "rozp" And Right(plik.Name, 4) = ".pdf" Then
        Selection.TypeText plik.Name
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
Next plik


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you perhaps put it in the normal.dotx template?

Comment: No, I didn't. However, the public submodule appears in such Word documents that it shouldn't appear.

Comment: Could you describe, please, the steps you used to create the macro (not typing the code, but how you put it in what kind of file - that kind of thing)? You mention "public submodule" but the code you show is a Private Sub - please be very specific and accurate in your problem description.

Comment: Of course, I thought about a Private Sub. I apologize for that mistake.

Comment: I created a Word document, wrote the macro and saved the file with '.docm' extension. Next, I copied that file to several another paths and changed its name. After that, my macro fires on almost all Word documents after opening them, even if they are not copies of the original document.

Comment: I opened the normal.dotx file. Although I didn't put the code in that template, I saw the private sub in it. I deleted the code and everything works properly.

Answer (score -1):

You probably stored it in normal.dotm document This code will apply to all documents. You should move it and store it in module that is in the document your are dealing with.

Edit 1: You created a .docm document but are you sure you stored your code in the docm document and not in the normal.dotm document?

Edit 2: I created a word test.docm document and put your code in a new module (under project(Test) -> Modules -> Module 1). Then I started the code and it create 1 paragraph per files in the same folder (giving they respect the check in your IF condition). Then, I transfered that code in Project(Test) -> Microsoft Word Objects -> ThisDocument; so it works at opening. It does exactly the same as intended at the opening.
Finally, I tested opening other word documents (docx and docm) in the same folder and the code did not run.

I cannot reproduce your problem running the exact same code. This reinforce the idea that you wrote your code under Normal -> Microsoft Word Object -> ThisDocument while in the VBA frame.

Have a good day,

Jonathan.

Comment: That's not true - just any "dotm document" will NOT apply to all documents. And what do you mean by "a dedicated module"? Also, please read the StackOverflow guidelines in [help] about communicating on the site: signature lines are frowned on.

Comment: I didn't use a '.dotm' extension. I used '.docm'.

Comment: Reply to Edit 1: Yes. I didn't even open the normal.dotm file as well as I wasn't aware of its existance at the time I was writing the macro.